# Why do these two await lines execute in parallel?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

In below code, both c and c2 variables are awaiting for different promise instances and should run in serial but when run, the program completes in 100 miliseconds instead of 200.

```js
function a1() {
  return new Promise((x, y) => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      x(5);
    }, 100);
  });
}

async function run() {
  let t1 = Date.now();
  let b = a1();
  let b2 = a1();

  let c = await b;
  let c2 = await b2;
  console.log(Date.now() - t1);
}

run().then(function () {
  console.log('@');
});
```

Why is this behavior legal if await is defined as a serial operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `a1()` for both `b` and `b2` when declaring them. Thus, by the time you await, the timeouts have already run and they each hold a promise, the await just resolves those promises.

If you want to see the full delay you should asign `a1` to your `b` variables and then await the calls when declaring `c`, or simply await `a1()` twice.

```
  let b = a1;
  let b2 = a1;

  let c = await b();
  let c2 = await b2();
```

```js
function a1() {
  return new Promise((x, y) => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      x(5);
    }, 100);
  });
}

async function run() {
  let t1 = Date.now();

  let b = await a1();
  let b2 = await a1();
  
  console.log(Date.now() - t1);
}

run().then(function () {
  console.log('@');
});
```

Comment: Do you mean, they start running the moment promise is returned from a1()?

Comment: They start running as soon as you declare your new Promise, so as soon as you call `a1()`

Comment: Then I guess this works on any data structure like an array of promises, tree of promises, etc. So awaiting all of them becomes same as awaiting just one of them.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik - *"Do you mean, they start running the moment promise is returned from a1()?"* Yes -- well, actually, earlier than that, as soon as `setTimeout` is called, which is before the promise is returned. The function you pass to `new Promise` is run *immediately* and *synchronously*, before `new Promise` returns the promise. By the time you get the promise, the timer is already running. Promises don't **do** anything, they just provide a standard means of observing the completion of things.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik - *"So awaiting all of them becomes same as awaiting just one of them."* No. Awaiting one of them just awaits that one. Any other asynchronous process being observed by some *other* promise may or may not complete when the one you're awaiting completes.

Comment: Then its like a std::thread of C++ but not really multithread since Javascript is single thread. Then await in Javascript is join() in C++. I have misunderstood the await as a running initiation like deferred scheduling.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik - I strongly recommend **not** trying to reason about JavaScript promises and tasks using C++ multithreading as your model, there are too many fundamental differences (such as the single-thread-per-realm thing you mentioned). But yes, `await` doesn't *start* anything. It just waits for it to finish.